Network bridge br0 is preventing host from being accessed outside of local intranet
I have created a bridge (br0) in /etc/network/interfaces for my VM (hypervisor is KVM).
This allows the VM to access the internet as expected, however the host cannot be accessed by other computers, except for the local network. For example, SSH gives the following error:
ssh: connect to host <host> port 22: No route to host

The VM is supposed to have some server software installed, so I cannot use a NAT connection for it.
Here are the contents of the /etc/network/interfaces file:
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.26
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.0.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        bridge_ports enp4s0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_maxwait 5


Does SSH give you that error on the VM host, connecting to other systems, or does it give you that error on some other system, connecting to the VM host?

@grawity_u1686 To clarify, I'm trying to connect from my main computer to the server with the bridge when that error occurs, but it works fine if I use the local IP specified in the /etc/network/interfaces file, however it doesn't work when trying to use my global IP. The port is correctly forwarded.

That sounds more-or-less 'normal', and usually has nothing to do with bridges – did it work before setting up the bridge? (What you describe is a common NAT hairpin problem...)

@grawity_u1686 Yes, it did work before the bridge was made.

Shouldn't netmask be 255.255.254.0?

@TomYan That doesn't work either.

The network and gateway values were wrong. I used Windows 7 to figure out that they should both be set to 192.168.1.1 for my case. The values I used to figure this out are called "IPv4 DHCP Server" and "IPv4 Default Gateway" in Windows 7 respectively.
